# import JS (websql) library in Vue

Tags: vue.js, web-sql

I'm used to use this WebSQL wrapper: https://github.com/psayre23/WebSQL

I want to use this in my Vue project, but I can't get it working. I did the following:

```
import * as WebSQL from './WebSQL';
var db = WebSQL('test');

Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$db', { value: db });
```

also tried:

```
require('./WebSQL');
var db = WebSQL('test');

Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$db', { value: db });
```

But I keep getting:

```
Can't find variable: WebSQL (WebSQL.js:429)
```

Comment: Please don't use `WebAPI`. Contrary to the authors writing, `IndexedDB` has betters support and works on all phones and almost all features are supported across all browsers (including IE11).

Comment: Does IndexedDB supports queries like left joins? and 'where' queries? I like websql because its very fast and there will be like 20000 rows in it. It will only be used on android and iPhone.

Comment: Take a look at jsstore - http://jsstore.net. It provides sql like apis.

Answer (score 1):

The repo you have provided is **out-of-date**. Last update was `5 years ago`.

- The library is not compatible with `webpack`.
  E.g. this will not work

```js
import * as WebSQL from './WebSQL';
```

- It relies on global availability of `WebSQL` which is [deprecated](https://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage). As @Ohgodwhy noticed, use **[`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)** instead. If you'd prefer a simple API, try libraries such as [localForage](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/), [dexie.js](http://dexie.org/), [ZangoDB](https://github.com/erikolson186/zangodb) and [JsStore](http://jsstore.net/) that make IndexedDB more programmer-friendly.